# I want to display my related list onl ywhen the list has records

Tags: visualforce, javascript

i want to display my relatedlist when the related list have records and i don't want to display my relatedlist when the related list has no records.

i have wriiten this code.
I am not achiving my requirement  in the pdf by this code
can u people help me with this.

```
 <div id="Childs">
  <apex:relatedList list="bucketrate__r" title="Bucket Rate Factoring Fee" rendered="{!opportunity.bucketrate__r.size()>0}"/>
```

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#Childs a').attr('target','_blank');
    });
    </script>
```

---

```
..Error: Unknown function opportunity.bucketrate__r.size. Check spelling
```

Comment: You mention PDF: I'm pretty sure no JavaScript runs when a page is rendered as PDF.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct child relationship name? Often they are plural, so you would in that case use `opportunity.bucketrates__r.size`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<apex:relatedList list="bucketrate__r" title="Bucket Rate Factoring Fee" rendered="{!opportunity.bucketrate__r.size>0}"/>
```

Try above. Its only .Size not method notation in Visualforce.

I would say to use JSENCODE or HTMLENCODE as security best practice when you are doing logic like that .

Comment: if i wrote like this then its showing an error as [error: TEXT field not found in opportunity]

Comment: Can you add your whole code ?